# My themes breakpoint file isn't being loaded

Tags: theming, 8

For some unknown reason my theme is not loading it's breakpoint yml file, is there anything that could block this from being loaded?

Edit:

Filenames correct if I copy it to another folder it works. Also breakpoints definitely enabled.

Comment: Is the breakpoint module enabled? also the file should be `themename.breakpoints.yml`.

Comment: Aren't theme breakpoints unsupported at this time?